Movie where 3 escaped prisoners take over high school
I'm trying to identify a movie that I think was made in the 70s or 80s. There 3 prisoners - one mastermind, one gay guy, and a black guy. They escape together
and while they're on the run, they break into some guy's house. The black guy rapes the wife while the mastermind and gay guy sit in the living room playing a piano and drinking.
Another scene had an old psychiatrist trying to help a young girl overcome her fears with hypnosis and putting snakes on her. The prisoners break into his house but the old guy scares them off by throwing the snakes at them.
The last major scene was them breaking into a high school and taking a martial arts class hostage, but then the class uses the martial arts on the prisoners to take them down.
It was filmed in USA, in English, don't remember any of the actors.
